# Update Value to null on CakePhp 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I have that table:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

records:

```
insert  into `clients`(`id`,`name`,`created`,`type`) values 
(1,'test1','2020-08-07 13:58:35',''),
(2,'test2','2020-08-07 13:58:53','1'),
(3,'test3','2020-08-07 13:58:55','1');
```

**How can I update the blank registry value to NULL using CakePhp 3?**

I tried to use array_filter and it just keeps the value as it is in the database, I tried to put the array key 'type' => null, and the value remains blank ...

**Controller action:**

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
  if (empty($id)) {
    $this->Flash->error(__('This page can not be access'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
  }
 try {
    $client = $this->Clients->get($id);
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    $this->Flash->error(__('Client not found'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
  }
  if ($this->getRequest()->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $post = array_filter($this->getRequest()->getData());
    $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $post);
    if($this->Clients->save($client)){
      $this->Flash->success(__('Client data has updated.'));
    } else {
      $this->Flash->error(__('Error!'));
    }
  }
  $this->set(compact('client'));
}
```

Comment: That the right SQL? It lists field `client_id` not `type`? Also maybe post your actual Cake code?

Comment: The insert declares that you are going to provide 4 values but you are providing 5...

Comment: OK @ahoffner, i put the controller action edit.

Comment: no @Juan , have 4 provides and 4 values...

Comment: Do you have `'quoteIdentifiers' => true` in the Datasource configs in your app.php? `type` is a reserved keyword

Comment: `'quoteIdentifiers' => true,` => my app.php

Comment: @FelipeSá you are right I counted wrong. What im also not sure could cause problems is that you have declared the id as autoincrement but then you are trying to assgined manually. Have you tried not assigning it manually?

Comment: @Juan do't worry so much about the inserts, they are just to exemplify the contents of the table. My problem is about this `type` field. I can't update the value to NULL using CakePhp

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration file :

```
php bin/cake.php bake migration fixNullValueInClientTable
```

Next, in your migration file put this :

```
<?php

use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class FixNullValueInClientTable extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $this->query("UPDATE clients SET 'type' = NULL WHERE 'type'=''");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure your phinx.yml :

```
paths:
  migrations:
    - "%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/config/Migrations"
  seeds:
    - "%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/config/Seeds"

environments:
  default_migration_table: phinxlog
  default_database: YOURDATABASE
  local:
    adapter: mysql
    host: YOURHOST
    name: YOURDATABASE
    user: USER
    pass: PASSWORD
    port: 3306
    charset: utf8
```

(You can add as many entries as you have server)

Execute phinx on the local env :

```
vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e local
```

And it's done.

Never fix your tables inside your app, use a migration file, this way you can mass-apply the configuration on all your DB servers on different env.